# Video playback on UWP from HTTP stream

Tags: uwp

I tried to do a simple video playback following (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/media-playback)[this article] by adding the following

```
<MediaPlayerElement AutoPlay="True" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Source="http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4" />
```

to my page XAML. But apparently, this does not work. Is this because we can only use local file for the `Source`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this because we can only use local file for the Source?

No, you can set http stream for the source. But the [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement.source.aspx) property of [`MediaPlayerElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement.aspx) is `IMediaPlaybackSource`  not Uri directly. You need to create [MediaSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn930905) from Uri code behind. Code as follows.

XAML Code

```
 <MediaPlayerElement AutoPlay="True" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" x:Name="mediaplayer" Height="400" Width="400" />
```

Code behind

```
  public MainPage()
  {
      this.InitializeComponent();
      Uri pathUri = new Uri("http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4");
      mediaplayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(pathUri);
  }
```

You can also use [MediaElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242926) control which its [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.source) type is Uri directly.

```
<MediaElement Height="400" Width="400" AutoPlay="True" Source="http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4"></MediaElement>
```

Comment: Hello, is it possible to add authentification to the http connection. My stream is accessible only with a user a password and UWP does not support the schema <https://user:password@link>. Thank you very much @Sunteen